# Compare two CSV files and look for matches Python

Tags: python, list, csv, compare, string-matching

I have two CSV files that are like

CSV1

```
H1,H2,H3
arm,biopsy,forearm
heart,leg biopsy,biopsy
```

organs.csv

```
arm
leg
forearm
heart
skin
```

I need to compare both the files and get an output list like this [arm,forearm,heart,leg] but the script that I'm currently working on doesn't give me any output (I want leg also in the output, though it is mixed with biopsy in the same cell). Here's the code so far. How can I get all the matched words?

```
import csv
import io

alist, blist = [], []

with open("csv1.csv", "rb") as fileA:
    reader = csv.reader(fileA, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        alist.append(row)
with open("organs.csv", "rb") as fileB:
    reader = csv.reader(fileB, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        blist.append(row)

first_set = set(map(tuple, alist))
secnd_set = set(map(tuple, blist))

matches = set(first_set).intersection(secnd_set)
print matches
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv

alist, blist = [], []

with open("csv1.csv", "rb") as fileA:
    reader = csv.reader(fileA, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        for row_str in row:
            alist += row_str.strip().split()

with open("organs.csv", "rb") as fileB:
    reader = csv.reader(fileB, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        blist += row

first_set = set(alist)
second_set = set(blist)

print first_set.intersection(second_set)
```

Basically, iterating through the csv file via csv reader returns a row which is a list of the items (strings) like this ['arm', 'biopsy', 'forearm'], so you have to sum lists to insert all of the items.

On the other hand, to remove duplications only one set conversion via the set() function is required, and the intersection method returns another set with the elements.

Comment: Thank you. But that doesn't still give me 'leg' in the output.

Comment: Yep, you're right. To make it work you have two ways:

1) Add a comma after the leg word on csv1.csv
2) Split into words each element on csv1.csv

I will edit the answer to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Change the part reading from `csv1.csv` to:

```
with open("csv1.csv", "rb") as fileA:
    reader = csv.reader(fileA, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        # append all words in cell
        for word in row:
            alist.append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

I  would treat the CSV files as text files, get a lists of all the words in the first and the seconds, then iterate over the first list to see if any exactly match any in the second list.